# if the IF statement is true view new activity

Tags: java, android

```
                   if(res.equals("5510"))
                    checkback.setText("Correct version");
               //
                else
                    checkback.setText("Incorrect version, please update. \n Your current version is " + getString(R.string.versioncode));
```

How do i get it so that if the IF statement is true then it'll start and view mainactivity.class?

I put intent in but when i did it showed up with a bunch of errors

Comment: show us the errors you got please?

Comment: could you just tell me what you would put inside the if statement?

Comment: If youget errors then post them with your question! It makes it a million times easier to work out where the issue is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, but replace "CurrentActivity.this" with the name of the activity your calling it from.

```
if(res.equals("5510")){
    checkback.setText("Correct version");
    Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActiviy.this, mainactivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
}else{
    checkback.setText("Incorrect version, please update. \n Your current version is " + getString(R.string.versioncode));
}
```

If you still get errors then post the errors you get - it makes it a million times easier to work out where the issue is!